# What is the recommended version of ehcache for shiro?

Tags: ehcache, shiro

I have been through the Apache Shiro 1.2.3 website and I can not find the recommended version of Ehcache.

The latest version of Ehcache, 2.8.2 does not work.

An older version of Ehcache, 2.4.7 *seems* to work.

Any help, feedback on what you use?

Comment: You should elaborate on what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`shiro-root` pom](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/shiro/shiro-root/1.2.3/shiro-root-1.2.3.pom) for version `1.2.3` indicates that they build against Ehcache `2.5.0`.

Comment: it was so obvious to look there... Thanks.